# Is there somewhere to run Dart code interactively?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to run Dart code interactively, as I would do with Javascript in the browser developer tools console or Ruby in irb?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org) (maintained by the Dart team)
- [try.dartlang.org](http://try.dartlang.org) (maintained by the Dart team)
- https://www.codebox.io/stack/dart
- http://runnable.com/ ([angular example](http://runnable.com/UvL5t92j1pVCAAAQ/angular-dart-tutorial-chapter-05))
- http://www.compileonline.com/execute_dart_online.php
- http://dev.dartlab.org/
- you can run Dart code in the console of the browsers developer tools in Dartium (the Dart development Browser - a Chromium derivative with integrated Dart VM) When Chrome gets the Dart VM it will very probably support this too.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to run Dart code in the Dartium console.:
void main() {
  var a = 'sugar is sweet';
  var b = a.replaceAll('sugar', 'maple syrup');
  print(b);
}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: In the toolbar of the console (below the tabs Console/Search/Emulateion/Randering) is a dropdown that shows `<top frame>`. Here you need to select a Dart context, then you can execute Dart expressions. I don't use is myself so I don't know how convenient this is. I think it's mostly for debugging purposes but I guess it's similar to how JS can be used here.

Comment: I tried that in Dartium, the result was what I posted. It is also unclear to me how to run Dart code in Codebox or Runnable :(. try.dartlang.org works great, so it's not too serious, but am I missing something?

Comment: In runnable.com you just click at the tab `client.dart` edit the code and click the run button above the edit window. With the `[+]` symbol you can add custom files and folders. In Codebox I can create and edit a project with Dart files but when I select the menu Project/Run I currently get only an error message.

Comment: For extra credit, there's also http://incr.try-dart-lang.appspot.com/ which the same as http://try.dartlang.org but with incremental compilation to speed things up (warning: it might have some issues, see the [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+PetervonderAh%C3%A9/posts/eGdSfRjMM26) by Peter von der Ahé).

Comment: It would be great to get jsfiddle and jsbin to support dart via dart2js.