# Is there something like jsfiddle.net for Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Does anybody know an online service like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), but for Angular Dart Code?

Comment: You can check the services listed in my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167886 if they support Angular.dart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there somewhere to run Dart code interactively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167886/is-there-somewhere-to-run-dart-code-interactively)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been through many services that claim to let you run Dart online, and it seems that:

- None support Angular (easily, anyway)
- Most require signups
- Some are outright broken

So, I think the answer is no :(

However, just this morning I wondered the same thing; and if I ever get time (which I won't), I think it'd make an interesting open source Dart project! :)